# socks5-https-client with Meteor fail to load

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use the Npm package socks5-https-client inside one of my meteor project.
I can load the main feature using :

```
var Socks5ClientHttps = Meteor.require('socks5-https-client');
```

But i can't load the Agent with :

```
var Socks5ClientHttpsAgent = Meteor.require('socks5-https-client/lib/Agent');
```

I get this error :

```
Error: Can't find npm module 'socks5-http-client/lib/Agent'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'npm' package?
```

I don't understand what happen, is it because i try to load a specific file from a package ?

Comment: http://meteorpedia.com/read/npm

Comment: ok, i know it and usually Meteor.require works well on main package. But i don't see any explanation about require a specific file from a package.